# Resolución de problema "dígitos saltarines" en Python

Tags: python, algoritmos

El problema es este https://www.aceptaelreto.com/pub/problems/v004/10/st/statements/Spanish/index.html

[Edit: añadido el enunciado por si el enlace deja de estar operativo]

> ## Enunciado
>
> Un número tiene sus dígitos saltarines si, empezando por el primero, se puede ir saltando de uno al siguiente tantos puestos como indiquen, y al final se llega de nuevo al principio habiendo pasado por todos ellos. Por ejemplo, el número 2.312 tiene a sus dígitos saltarines. Empezando por el primero, el primer 2, avanzamos dos dígitos y llegamos al 1. Desde él, avanzamos un dígito más, y llegamos al segundo 2. Desde él, avanzamos otros dos dígitos (dando la vuelta y empezando de nuevo por la izquierda), y llegamos al 3. Y desde éste, avanzamos tres veces, y llegamos otra vez al principio.
>
> [image: Ejemplo]
>
> **Entrada**. El programa deberá leer un primer número n indicando cuántos casos de prueba deberá procesar. A continuación vendrán n líneas, cada una con un número 0 < i < 109.
>
> Ningún número tendrá ceros superfluos a la izquierda.
>
> **Salida** Para cada caso de prueba, el programa escribirá "SALTARINES" si el número tiene a sus dígitos saltarines, y "NORMALES" en otro caso.
>
> Entrada de ejemplo:
>
> ```
> 4
> 2312
> 3
> 12
> 30
> ```
>
> Salida de ejemplo:
>
> ```
> SALTARINES
> SALTARINES
> NORMALES
> NORMALES
> ```

No sé cómo resolverlo, lo he intentado pero sale un batiburrillo de cosas que no llevan a ningún lado, lo dejo aquí:

```
n = int(input(""))
cont = 0
a = False
b = 0
b1 = 0
z = 0

while cont < n:

    num = input("")
    inum = int(num)
    contador = 0

    if 0 < inum < 10**9:

        while z < len(num):

            for i in num:
                if a == False:
                    b = num.index(i)
                    b1 = int(i)
                if a:
                    if num.index(i) == b + b1:
                        contador += b1
                        b = num.index(i)
                       b1 = int(i)
                a = True
                z += 1
                if num.index(i) == num[-1]:
                    z = (b + b1)%len(num)

        if contador % len(num) == 0:
            print("SALTARINES")
        else:
            print("NORMALES")
    cont += 1
```

Lo siento si es un dolor de cabeza leerlo, acabo de empezar a programar y tampoco tengo mucha idea todavía.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solución en *pseudocódigo*

El problema es muy interesante. Aunque puede haber muchas formas de resolverlo, en python resulta particularmente simple lo siguiente.

- Tratamos el número como una cadena, para poder acceder fácilmente a sus dígitos individuales. Cada dígito tendrá un índice. Por ejemplo, el número "4321" tiene la cifra "4" en el índice 0, la cifra "3" en el indice 1, etc.
- Mantenemos una lista de booleanos con tantos elementos como cifras tenga el número. Cada uno indica si ya ha sido visitado o no el correspondiente índice del dato.
- Comenzamos por el `indice=0` y repetimos en bucle lo siguiente:
- Mientras ese `indice` no haya sido visitado:

  - Marcarlo como visitado
  - Extraer la cifra que hay en ese índice
  - El nuevo índice será igual al anterior más la cifra extraída (aplicando módulo para que si se sale por la derecha vuelva a entrar por la izquierda)
- Del bucle anterior se saldrá cuando se vuelva a un dígito ya visitado. Entonces:

  - Si hemos llegado al índice 0 de nuevo, y **todos** los demás índices han sido visitados, el número es "saltarín"
  - En caso contrario es "normal" (esto es, si volvemos al índice 0 sin haber visitado todos, o bien si hemos visitado todos pero no terminamos en el índice 0)

**Antes de seguir leyendo** intenta implementar tú mismo en Python el pseudocódigo anterior.

### Implementación

¡No la leas sin intentarlo tú antes!

> `def is_saltarin(dato):
>   dato = str(dato)              # Convertirlo en cadena
>   visitado = [False]*len(dato)  # Lista de booleanos
>   indice = 0
>   while not visitado[indice]:
>     visitado[indice] = True
>     cifra = int(dato[indice])
>     indice = (indice + cifra) % len(dato)
>   return indice==0 and all(visitado)`

Ahora el programa "principal" se limita a pedir los datos y enviarlos a esa función:

```
n = input("Numero de elementos: ")
for i in range(int(n)):
  dato = input("Dato: ")
  if is_saltarin(int(dato)):
     print("SALTARINES")
  else:
     print("NORMALES")
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

```
Numero de elementos: 4
Dato: 2312
SALTARINES
Dato: 3
SALTARINES
Dato: 12
NORMALES
Dato: 30
NORMALES
```

Comment: Casi me salió con el pseudocódigo, y vi una cosa que no sabía, y es que una función se puede utilizar como condición. ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: @Malher400 Claro que puedes. Si la función retorna un booleano, ese resultado puede formar parte de otra expresión. En este caso uso la función `all()`, poco conocida pero muy útil, porque recibe un array de booleanos y te retorna `True` sólo si todos ellos son `True`.